# @RequestParam in Spring MVC handling optional parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible for a Spring controller to handle both kind of requests?

1) `http://localhost:8080/submit/id/ID123432?logout=true`

2) `http://localhost:8080/submit/id/ID123432?name=sam&password=543432`

If I define a single controller of the kind:

```
 @RequestMapping (value = "/submit/id/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,   
 produces="text/xml")
public String showLoginWindow(@PathVariable("id") String id,
                              @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
                              @RequestParam("name") String username,
                              @RequestParam("password") String password,
                              @ModelAttribute("submitModel") SubmitModel model,
                              BindingResult errors) throws LoginException {...}
```

the HTTP request with "logout" is not accepted.

If I define two controllers to handle each request separately, Spring complains with the exception "There is already 'Controller' bean method ... mapped".

Comment: Read this article: http://codeflex.co/java-spring-rest-api-with-empty-or-optional-parameters/

Answer (score 283, accepted):

**Before Java 8 and Spring 5 (but works with Java 8+ and Spring 5+ too)**

You need to give `required = false` for `name` and `password` request parameters as well. That's because, when you provide just the `logout` parameter, it actually expects for `name` and `password` because they are still "implicitly" mandatory.

It worked when you just gave `name` and `password` because `logout` wasn't a mandatory parameter thanks to `required = false` already given for `logout`.

**Update for Java 8 and Spring 5 (and above)**

You can now use the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class from Java 8 onwards to make the parameters optional.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleRequest(@RequestParam("paramName") Optional<String> variableName) {
    String paramValue = variableName.orElse("");
    // use the paramValue
}
```

Answer (score 194):

As part of `Spring 4.1.1` onwards you now have full support of Java 8 `Optional` ([original ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12171)) therefore in your example both requests will go via your single mapping endpoint as long as you replace `required=false` with Optional for your 3 params logout, name, password:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/submit/id/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,   
 produces="text/xml")
public String showLoginWindow(@PathVariable("id") String id,
                              @RequestParam(value = "logout") Optional<String> logout,
                              @RequestParam("name") Optional<String> username,
                              @RequestParam("password") Optional<String> password,
                              @ModelAttribute("submitModel") SubmitModel model,
                              BindingResult errors) throws LoginException {...}
```

Comment: @VibhavChaddha you can use something like this: 
 if (idOfUser.isPresent()){
            System.out.println("idOfUser: "+ idOfUser.get());
  }

Comment: Intellij warning: 'Optional<Long>' used as type for parameter 'requestedTimelineStart' less... (Strg+F1) 
Inspection info: Reports any uses of java.util.Optional<T>, java.util.OptionalDouble, java.util.OptionalInt, java.util.OptionalLong or com.google.common.base.Optional as the type for a field or a parameter. Optional was designed to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result". Using a field with type java.util.Optional is also problematic if the class needs to be Serializable, which java.util.Optional is not.

Comment: This should be the new correct answer with Java 8 I believe.

Comment: @PeMa it's a controversial warning. Personally I think it's much clearer to use `Optional` as parameters instead of `null` checks. Yes, parameters can be `null` itself, but returned `Optional` value can also be `null`.
Especially in this case when Spring handles null parameters internally when wrapping it in Optional.

Answer (score 43):

Create 2 methods which handle the cases. You can instruct the `@RequestMapping` annotation to take into account certain parameters whilst mapping the request. That way you can nicely split this into 2 methods.

```
@RequestMapping (value="/submit/id/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, 
                 produces="text/xml", params={"logout"})
public String handleLogout(@PathVariable("id") String id, 
        @RequestParam("logout") String logout) { ... }

@RequestMapping (value="/submit/id/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, 
                 produces="text/xml", params={"name", "password"})
public String handleLogin(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestParam("name") 
        String username, @RequestParam("password") String password, 
        @ModelAttribute("submitModel") SubmitModel model, BindingResult errors) 
        throws LoginException {...}
```

Comment: what will happen when someone passes both logout, name and password to the URL ? Just read the documentation, it says `!myParam style expressions indicate that the
  * specified parameter is not supposed to be present in the request.` got to try.

Comment: It will find the best match, it probably will try to use the `handleLogin` else it will give an exception stating no mapping can be found.

Comment: Just one note: from the security perspective logout should only accept POST requests, so there _should_ be 2 methods and it doesn't make any sense to keep their URL the same then.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for mapping Optional parameters with `Pojo`, same can be done like below.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/submit/id/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,   
 produces="text/xml")
public String showLoginWindow(@PathVariable("id") String id,
                              LoginRequest loginRequest,
                              @ModelAttribute("submitModel") SubmitModel model,
                              BindingResult errors) throws LoginException {...}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
//@AllArgsConstructor - Don't use this
public class LoginRequest {
    private Optional<String> logout = Optional.empty();
    private Optional<String> username = Optional.empty();
    private Optional<String> password = Optional.empty();
}
```

**Note**: Do not use `@AllArgsConstructor` on `POJO` else it will initialize the fields as null.