# How to check a Long for null in java

Tags: java, null, long-integer

How do I check a Long value for null in Java?

Will this work?

```
if ( longValue == null) { return blah; }
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Primitive data types cannot be `null`.  Only `Object` data types can be `null`.

There are 8 primitive types in Java:

| Data Type | Size | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| byte | 1 byte | Int8 |
| short | 2 bytes | Int16 |
| int | 4 bytes | Int32 |
| long | 8 bytes | Int64 |
| float | 4 bytes | Single |
| double | 8 bytes | Double |
| boolean | 1 bit | Boolean |

If you use `Long` (wrapper class for `long`) then you can check for `null`'s:

```
Long longValue = null;

if(longValue == null)
```

Answer (score 19):

If it is `Long` object then You can use `longValue == null` or you can use  `Objects.isNull(longValue)` method in Java 7+ projects .

Please check [Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) for more info.

Answer (score 12):

If the `longValue` variable is of type `Long` (the wrapper class, not the primitive `long`), then yes you can check for null values.

A primitive variable needs to be initialized to some value explicitly (e.g. to `0`) so its value will never be null.

Answer (score 10):

You can check Long object for null value with `longValue == null` ,
you can use  `longValue == 0L` for long (primitive), because default value of long is 0L, but it's result will be true if longValue is zero too

Answer (score 3):

Of course Primitive types cannot be null. But in Java 8 you can use Objects.isNull(longValue) to check. 
Ex. If(Objects.isNull(longValue))

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already primitives can not be set to the Object type null.

What I do in such cases is just to use `-1` or `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Long you can check if it's null unless you go for long (as primitive data types cant be null while Long instance is a object)

```html
Long num; 

if(num == null) return;
```

For some context, you can also prefer using Optional with it to make it somehow beautiful for some use cases.
Refer [@RequestParam in Spring MVC handling optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373696/requestparam-in-spring-mvc-handling-optional-parameters)

Answer (score -7):

As primitives(long) can't be null,It can be converted to wrapper class of that primitive type(ie.Long) and null check can be performed.

If you want to check whether long variable is null,you can convert that into Long and check,

```
long longValue=null;

if(Long.valueOf(longValue)==null)
```

Comment: You will never get `null` value for `Long.valueOf()` operation.