# Optional parameter in Java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I want to update the user with a name and/or image.

The name is always on the input because I fetched from the database but the fileUpload is optional.

**How do I make my controller handle an optional parameter for the fileUpload?**

Atm, if I don't upload something I'm getting

> HTTP Status 400 - Required request part 'fileUpload' is not present

Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateUser(HttpSession session,@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile image) {
    String loggedUser = session.getAttribute("loggedUser").toString();
    return User.updateUser(loggedUser,name,image);
}
```

Ajax

```
function updateUserSettings() {
var name = $('#userName').val();
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", name);
formData.append("fileUpload", file);
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/user/update',
    data: formData,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@RequestParam in Spring MVC handling optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373696/requestparam-in-spring-mvc-handling-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
... @RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile image
```

to:

```
... @RequestParam(value="fileUpload", required=false) MultipartFile image
```

Refer to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) for more info on the available switches.