# How to send a single word(no key) JSON to springMVC?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, binding, postman

I have an API for front side,I use postman to send a single number 8.

[I want to send like this way in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vk2U.png)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/query",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String query(@RequestBody Integer number ){  

    return dao.query(number);
}
```

but now the front side say they can not send a single word with no key-value
in json,I don't want to create an object just use that once to binding,
how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [requestparam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373696/requestparam-in-spring-mvc-handling-optional-parameters)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String query(@RequestParam("number") Integer number){
  return dao.query(number);
}
```

The request should be like `/query?number=8`

Comment: @detail0805 that is not possible,,,when you say json it means key value pair is must.

Comment: ok,I check it for js api,it will be possible to send single parameter ,but its not officially ...so you are the right .

Answer (score 0):

Change Integer to String and you are good to go without doing anything else. Hope this helps you.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/query",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public String query(@RequestBody String number ){  

      return dao.query(number);
 }
```